# How do I save history in an android app?

Tags: android, listview, history

I have a listview called history that I call every time that I so something significant (ie open or close the app or record some info) The problem I have is that it records things from top to bottom meaning the most recent information is on the bottom of the listview. The second problem I have is that the listview gets deleted after the app is turned off. How do people usually save their history? (ie shared preferences can only store one variable and thats not enough, I would like to save a maximum of 30 entries to the listview)

Thanks

Comment: Umm, history of what? Why do you need a listview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option I use is to JSON encode my history list and store the resulting string to SharedPreferences. You can then order it as well (simply add items to the List that backs the ListView with new events first) and save it and restore it from the SharedPreferences file.

EDIT: Try something like this:

```
org.json.JSONArray tracking_users = new org.json.JSONArray();
tracking_users.put("history 1");
tracking_users.put("history 2");
tracking_users.put("history 3");
```

Comment: Thats a great idea, I only know how to extract data from a JSON, how would I put date into it? eg  org.json.JSONObject obj = new org.json.JSONObject(response);
   JSONArray tracking_users = obj.getJSONArray("d");

Comment: Just a quick logic question. I don't want the history to record EVERYTHING forever. I would like it to only record the past 30 events. Since tracking_users(my JSON array) fills its spots from tracking_users[0]-tracking_users[29] how do I start deleting the oldest post in place for the newest one. And as far as adding the items to the list with new events first were you talking about using a for loop and recording from the largest position to the 0th position? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately altering a JSONArray is astonishingly painful because JSONArray doesn't include methods to remove items. You'll need to rebuild the entire array each time you want to add an entry using the top 29 items from the existing array (or use something like json-simple (see http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/) which has proper List semantics and lets you remove items (see http://alex-public-doc.s3.amazonaws.com/json_simple-1.1/org/json/simple/JSONArray.html)). If you use the List built that way into an ArrayAdapter then it should display things nicely in a latest-event-first fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider using a database to store the Log of these events, tends to be more efficient.

See one of these for an [introduction to android databases](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=android+database+example)